# Query to get result from another id in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, case, where-clause

I have the following simple table

```
product_id    vendor_id    product_gtin    product_parent_id
646           1            123456789       0
4502          2            202020255       646
```

As a result I would like to get the product gtin for the id 4502 from the product_parent

Result example:

```
product_id    vendor_id    product_gtin    product_parent_id
646           1            123456789       0
4502          2            123456789       646
```

.

```
SELECT product_id, vendor_id, case when vendor_id !=1 then (select product_gtin from `products` where product_id = product_parent_id) else product_gtin end as gtin, product_parent_id FROM `products` where product_id in (646, 4502)
```

My problem is that while I run the query it does not know which id I refer to. So I get NULL as result for product_gtin for id 4502.

Any suggestions how to solve it would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use table aliases:

```
select product_id, vendor_id, 
    case when vendor_id <> 1 
        then (select product_gtin from `products` p1 where p1.product_id = p.product_parent_id) 
        else product_gtin 
    end as gtin, 
    product_parent_id 
from `products` p
where product_id in (646, 4502)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use self `left join` instead of sub-query with proper aliases to refer to columns as we are using same table twice.

```
select p.product_id, 
       p.vendor_id, 
       case when p.vendor_id != 1 then p1.product_gtin else p.product_gtin end as gtin, 
       p.product_parent_id 
 from `products` p lefr join `products` p1 on p1.product_id = p.product_parent_id
 where p.product_id in (646, 4502)
```